# Samsung SmartView like application for Windows/OSX

Tags: android, windows, macos, samsung-mobile, samsung-smart-tv

Samsung has a SmartView app for Samsung Smart TV users on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.smartview.tz&hl=en) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/samsung-smartview/id359580639?mt=8). The app allows users to remote control their TV and also view TV content on smartphones (on same network as TV).

The dual view no longer seems to be working for TV's released after 2012 due to content restriction policy. But few TV's ([example](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/tv-audio-video/television/led-tv/UA55F6400ARXZN-spec)) do support clone view.

How can a similar application be created for Windows/OSX, that allows the users to remote control their TV using PC, and also view TV content?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't find the old Samsung SmartTV SDK for that particular functionality, you should try to see if running an Android emulator on a high-end Windows/OSX machine (with Android x86 Emulation turned on) would do the trick.

I suppose you could also try using [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)/shark, to sniff and inspect the traffic between your phone and the TV, to try to reverse-engineer the protocol, but that would go way beyond my own level of expertise.